# Являются ли следующие определения однородными?!

Tags: пунктуация

Никак не могу разобраться с этим, кажется, простым правилом. Можно ли для проверки вставлять союз "и"? Здесь вставить не получается, значит, определения неоднородны.

Конструирование — это средство мирной скрытой широчайшей борьбы компаний...

Answer (score 1):

Конструирование — это средство мирной, скрытой широчайшей борьбы компаний...

Думаю, что два первых определения могут раскрывать одну тему - теневой, без внешних проявления агрессии характер борьбы. Три неоднородных определения здесь плохо читаются.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

У нас вот что удивительно: чем больше возможностей для авторского творчества, тем более трудной кажется задача.

1) Все прилагательные обозначают разные признаки и могут считаться неоднородными. Однако читается такой вариант плохо: странное сочетание двух абстрактных и одного качественного прилагательного в превосходной степени.

Хорошо читаются, например, такие варианты: "Впереди шёл бледный высокий курчавый юноша. Рядом с церковью стоял высокая узкая деревянная колокольня". Здесь уж точно сближать нечего.

2) Все три признака можно сблизить, тогда прилагательные будут однородными. Это значит, что они будут раскрывать одну тему, в нашем случае создавать единый образ. Этот вариант нормально читается, лучше применить его, чтобы долго не думать.

3) Можно было сблизить значения двух первых прилагательных, но это креативное решение, как я вижу, не находит понимания. Но в то же время оно в наибольшей степени выражает авторскую свободную позицию.

Comment: София, иногда ваши советы просто шокируют. Вот **так** запятые тут не поставит даже троечник, ей-богу.

Аленка, здесь нет правильного варианта, потому что определения некоторым образом исключают одно другое. Это как вялый треугольный неоднозначный суп.

Если надо кровь из носу оставить фразу без изменений, то либо ставьте две запятые, либо не ставьте ни одной. Одна – наихудшее решение.

Comment: Здравствуйте, Niemand. А почему бы Вам не ответить на своем поле, дать развернутый, убедительный ответ вместо выражения эмоций и личностных оценок. Будьте любезны объяснить, как вы понимаете однородность/неоднородность этих определений?  Я же считаю, что здесь возможны различные решения, и зависят они, скорее, от структуры предложения, а не от семантических связей прилагательных, которые можно трактовать достаточно свободно.

Comment: Если честно, то я тоже считаю, что должны быть либо две запятые, либо ни одной. И скорее последнее. А может быть решить так?
Конструирование — это средство широчайшей мирной, но скрытой борьбы компаний... Хотя я, скорее, оставлю без запятых...

Comment: Мне кажется, здесь дополнительно сбивает оксюморон "мирной борьбы". Ну не бывает мирной борьбы, если борьба не понарошку! Так что я бы "мирной" выбросил, и борьбу для благозвучия заменил: "...широчайшего скрытого противоборства"

Answer (score -1):

Аленка, а что вас смущает? Смысл в предложении: широчайшая борьба компании и мирная, и скрытая.

Comment: Не поняла вопроса. Смысл предложения я понимаю, но не понимаю, как определить, являются ли определения однородными. Про пузатый ореховый комод-то я все понимаю. Или яркое зимнее солнце. Но здесь смысл сложнее и я не понимаю, по какому принципу эти определения  можно объединить или наоборот разъединить... Мирной и скрытой ведь не скажешь, как и скрытой и широчайшей... Значит, все-таки неоднородные.  Но "Старуха закрыла свинцовые, погасшие глаза" - эпитеты, все из того же Розенталя. "И" не подставишь, а запятая, тем не менее, все равно ставится.

Comment: И также не очень понимаю, когда образуются синонимические отношения. Напр. "сплошная, беспросветная тьма" или "ровный, монотонный голос".

Comment: Есть такое понятие, как контекстуальная, авторская синонимия. Если у автора, например, ситец ассоциируется только с выцветшей, неяркой тканью, то бледные, ситцевые глазки у него будут однородными определениями. У вас все 3 могут быть однородными: мирная борьба = тихая = скрытая = беспрепятственная = потому и широко распространившаяся. София ответила вам подробно. Лично я склоняюсь к 2 запятым.